# Why FindComponent does not work in this context?

Tags: delphi

When I create a component at runtime, `FindComponent()` won't work. Here is my code:

```
var m : tmemo;
begin
m := tmemo.create(form1);
m.parent := form1;
m.name := 'mymemo';
m.align := alclient;
if (tmemo(findcomponent('mymemo')) <> nil) then showmessage('this should happen') else
showmessage('but this is what actually happens');
end;
```

I'd expect that `tmemo(findcomponent('mymemo'))` would return the memo I just created, but actually it returns nil. Why is that?

Comment: Are you just looking for `If Assigned(m) then...`?

Comment: What is the surrounding context of your code, i.e. where are you calling it from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FindComponent()` is a method of `TComponent`. It searches the components that are owned by the `TComponent` object it is called on.

`FindComponent()` doesn't work in your example because you are calling it on the wrong Owner. That is the only way it would return nil.

You are creating the `TMemo` object with the `Form1` object as its Owner, but then you are searching for the `TMemo` in the `Self` object. `Form1` and `Self` are clearly not pointing at the same object, hence why `FindComponent()` returns nil. You need to call `FindComponent()` on the `Form1` object instead, eg:

```pascal
var
  m : TMemo;
begin
  m := TMemo.Create(Form1);
  m.Parent := Form1;
  m.Name := 'mymemo';
  m.Align := alClient;
  if (Form1.FindComponent('mymemo') <> nil) then
    ShowMessage('this actually happens')
  else
    ShowMessage('this should not happen');
end;
```